# PayPal production working differently than sandbox

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I have built an application, that sends a notification url with the GUID of the logged in user to PayPal, and upon completion of purchase, the url is called, and after verification, the user database entry updates the column `purchased` from 0 to 1.

The user then clicks the return to app button, and the premium functionality displays based on the `purchased` column.

I have been testing this over the last few months in the sandbox.  100% of the times tested (including after this issue), the premium tab displays after purchase completion.

Client is thrilled, and gives the go ahead to move to production.  I have set up IPN with the *exact same URL*, I have changed literally nothing except switching from www.sandbox.paypal.com to www.paypal.com and changing the account listed from the sandbox business to the personal business.

Ths issue is, the button now doesn't show up, ***until***, you refresh the screen.  Clicking the "return to app" button, which previously was working as expected, now doesn't display the premium tab.  Once I click refresh - it then shows up.  If I switch everything back to the sandbox settings, boom - it works just fine again.

Here is the BuyNow button code with production account:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" id="buynowForm" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="ACCOUNT EMAIL">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Product">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10.00">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type='hidden' name='notify_url' value='http://app.com/purchase/<?php echo $data[0]['uid'] ?>'>
<input type='hidden' name='return' value='http://app.com/'>
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="cbt" value="Return to Product Plus">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHosted">
<input type="submit" class="hidden-print visible-print" border="0" name="buysubmit" value="Click For Product Plus" alt="Click for Product Plus">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
```

And here is the processing route called above:

```
$app->post('/purchase/:uid', function ($uid) use ($app) {

 $request = Slim::getInstance()->request();
 $inputs = json_decode($request->getBody());
 $db_conn = conn();

 $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate'; 
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) 
    { 
        if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
        { 
            $_POST[$key] = stripslashes($value); 
            $value = stripslashes($value); 
        } 
        $value = urlencode($value); 
        $req .= "&$key=$value"; 
    } 

    $url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
    $ch = curl_init();    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req); 
    $result = curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch); 

    if (strcmp ($result, "VERIFIED") == 0)
    { 
        $sql_st = 'UPDATE  `user_data` SET `purchased` = 1 WHERE uid=:uid';

          $sql = $db_conn->prepare($sql_st);
          if ($sql->execute(array('uid'=>$uid))) {
            $data = array('status' => "Ok");
          } else {
            $data = array('status' => print_r(mysql_error()));
          }
    } 
    else  
    { 
        // Did Not Process IPN Properly
    } 

});
```

*REALLY* hoping this is just something incredibly dumb on my part.  Any help/guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Tech support, btw, was no help at all here.  Still unsure of how to resolve.  Haven't found anything on a lag or queue, potentially causing a slow down.  Feeling very stumped at the moment.

Comment: This has been incredibly frustrating.  Testing has also been problematic, since the only method of testing is using the sandbox (which I get, I think).  If the only method of testing is the sandbox, and it works perfectly, then it should work in the production... UGH!

Comment: It appears to be the Instant Payment Notification is anything but instant.  Seems to take about 10-15 seconds,  most likely in a queue.  Working on a fix,  hope to report back soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially the solution here is one of two options -

1. Build a secondary method of completion - in other words, the IPN is not the first line of defense for a purchased upgrade to software.  Everything on my end is working, however the timing of the IPN (notify_url) call is too slow to make instant upgrades not exactly instant. Return them to a page that performs the upgrade then redirects.
2. Store the upgraded features behind a different route - this was PayPal's suggestion. Essentially, have app.com/basic and app.com/upgraded.  This isn't really ideal, nor would I suggest it as a permanent solution.

Summed up - this is a known issue with PayPal.  The sandbox and production workflows are basically different - not by function or API, but in usage - the production level account is getting hit more, and the time it takes to process the notifications are much slower.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Here is a link referring to the same issue - http://www.warriorforum.com/main-internet-marketing-discussion-forum/201089-paypal-ipn-delays-question.html